# What phrase is "o'clock" contracting?

Tags: contractions, time

I have been intrigued by the word *o'clock* since I learned English. Although there is an equivalent to this word in my native language (Spanish *en punto* meaning *on point* or *on the dot*) I want to know the origin of the term *o'clock*, especially why it has an apostrophe. Is it meant to contract *on the clock* or something similar?

Comment: Same as O'Brian, O'Reilly, O'Flanagan... son OF Brian, son OF Reilly...

Comment: It most certainly is not. "O" in Irish names is derived from the Irish word "uaidh" meaning grandson.

Comment: Colin Fine is correct, according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irish_name).

Comment: Flagged as general reference because a Google search for "o'clock" leads directly to several pages explaining it including three dictionaries.

Comment: [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/o'clock) suggests that this is the "shortened form of 'of the clock' or 'on the clock'; that is, 'according to the clock'."

Comment: Why is this question not GR? Aren't the up votes inappropriate and the answers questionable?

Comment: A long time ago the Irish Mr. O'Reilly told the man who fixed clocks: I'm going to call you Mr. O'Clock, because you're Irish and you're always on time! That's how it started.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to [The Time-traveller's Guide to Medieval England](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0224079948) 'of the clock' was used to describe time when it was being sliced in 24 equal parts (hours) of the day.

It was used to differentiate the practice, used equally as much, of using [solar time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_time), whereby the 7th hour would shift in actual time, however would always be 7/12ths of a solar day after sunrise, and the length of an hour would increase in summer and decrease in winter.

Comment: Ooh, I need to get that book.

Comment: I would recommend it, it's a great read (and, no I have no affiliation with it, the author or the publisher :) )

Comment: We should totally go back to solar time, at least for work hours. ;)

Comment: The last sentence is simple physics: heat expands and cold contracts, so of course the hours get longer in summer and shorter in winter.

Comment: Note that *daytime* hours expand in summer and contract in winter. *Nighttime* hours do just the opposite: they're longer in winter and shorter in summer.

Answer (score 8):

I believe it's "of the clock".

Comment: Thanks! I found [this](http://www.informatics.sussex.ac.uk/department/docs/punctuation/node20.html) among many links explaining the _o'clock_ contraction.

Comment: Yes, this is what they told me in elementary school.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, *o’clock* is a contraction of the phrase “of the clock”. *Online Etymology Dictionary* traces the phrase back to the 1640s; the contraction first appears around 1720.[¹](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=o%27clock)

Answer (score 2):

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=o%27clock) says it’s an abbreviation of *of the clock*, which makes sense phonetically—both the *f* in *of* and the *th* in *the* are reduced to null in some contexts, and it’s a very common phrase.

The earliest citation they give is 1720, which is fairly late; prior to that, the phrase was spelled out in full—even if it was pronounced the same.

Comment: And it continued to be spelled out in full well into the 19th century (source: just search for something like "ten of the clock" in google books or in some corpus).