# What is the meaning of "O" in "7 O'Clock"?

Tags: meaning, etymology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What phrase is “o'clock” contracting?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4643/what-phrase-is-oclock-contracting)

In this string:

> 7 O'Clock

What is **O** doing here? What is the meaning of **O**? Does it mean 7 `of` Clock? What is its history (how does it started being called like that)? Please explain.